# How can I output the results of multiple stored procedure activities into one destination table?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline that I am attempting to create that accepts 8 datasets. I've ironed out the details, and am creating it procedurally with a C# application.

Each dataset is accepted by a different stored procedure activity within the pipeline. This stored procedure returns a few rows of information.

I need the resulting information from each activity to go to a particular table in an Azure SQL Database.

However, when I try to assign all 8 activities to the same output dataset, I receive an error saying that this is not possible:

> ConflictingPipelineActivities: Activities  and  have the same output Dataset sprocMergeOutput.
>   Two activities cannot output the same Dataset over the same active period.

Is there a way I can wire this pipeline so that the 8 stored procedure activities send their output to a single table?

Notes:

The stored procedure calls are merge statements, and I am simply recording `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` and the # of rows done by each activity. I suppose I could technically have this same stored procedure reference the other database and do the work on that side, but I'm pretty sure I have to have outputs for any stored procedure activities anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating 8 ADF datasets that point to the same table?

Each activity will have its own dataset (proc) output.

Comment: I probably should have clarified that this is the obvious next step, but at that point I've got 3 datasets per table that I'm storing (one for source DB, one for destination, another for merge output), and I was hoping there would be a way to pipe the activities into a single dataset. This might be the only way to go, though.